# Form: Select in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I have no idea why the dropdown value do not save into database. I try to get the solution from the website but I still can't fix it.

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'receipt' available as request attribute". This is the error that I get it. Appreciate your help.

My JSP Page

```
     <form:form modelAttribute="receipt" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cart/checkout" method="get" >
        <form:select  path="payment_method">
            <form:option value="NONE"> --SELECT--</form:option>
            <form:option value="Online Payment">Online Payment></form:option>
            <form:option value="Grab Pay">Grab Pay></form:option>
        </form:select>
    </form:form>
```

My Controller

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/cart")
    public class ShoppingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/checkout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String checkout(@RequestParam(value="payment_method", required=false) String payment_method, 
                   Model model,@ModelAttribute("receipt") Receipt receipt) { 

    receipt.setPayment_method(payment_method);
    receipt.save(receipt);
    .
    .
    .

    }
```

My Model

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="receipt")
    public class Receipt {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name="receipt_id")
    private int receipt_id;

    @Column(name="date_time")
    private Date date_time;

    @Column(name="status")
    private boolean status;

    @Column(name="total_amount")
    private double total_amount;

    @Column(name="payment_method")
    private String payment_method;

    setter and getter....
    }
```

Comment: are you adding empty Receipt object in the model? from the controller method which returns the view that has `form` which you have shared above.

Comment: @Naqi what do you mean ??